# Analogy What is the difference between AC light and DC light or is there such a thing?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electrons

Is there a constant non changing static light? See analogy

Analogy As
 AC is for alternating current 
 DC is for direct current

AC for sine Waves/Movement/Varies to light
DC for + or - straight line/not moving/non changing/ non flickering

Update : Additional info on my question if my thinking is right (maybe or maybe not)

We can see light because it varies pulse or something like that? Can I say like pulsating/alternating like an AC?The question is, is there a constant like DC straight not changing?

**The question is analogy**

Comment: You mean like non linear optical processes like the dc polarization component optical rectification and the ac components like sum frequency generation?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a form of light that has a frequency of zero?

Comment: yes, somewhat like that, if is there such a thing? a constant light true DC

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you seem to think that light itself can be some form of DC, and that is not possible. Light of all frequencies is an alternating electromagnetic wave.

Comment: Are you asking about the behavior of the EM wave itself or about the source of power for a bulb?  The answers seem to be addressing the source of power, alternating electrical current (ac) or direct electrical current (dc).

Comment: @BillDOe yes analogy to AC alternate DC not alternate,  so your answer is all light are frequencies alternating

Comment: @BillN not power source of light bulb or bulb itself, just analogy

Comment: I suppose you could say that a constant electric field is "DC light", although it usually wouldn't be called as such. For example, take a set of charges at equilibrium, like a charged sphere. Its electric field will be constant in time.

Comment: @TobErnack yeah like that "constant in time" like this https://gradestack.com/JEE-Main-2015-Complete/Electric-Charge-and/Equilibrium-of-Charges/19504-3784-41364-study-wtw very nice!

Comment: Im also checking this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charged-particle_equilibrium since it says In order for this to occur, energy is needed, so in this case intervetion of something is needed which is equals to movement analogous to ac

Answer (score 2):

DC current in a simple circuit is in one direction, continuous, and at a constant value over short time intervals.  With this being the case, light from a bulb in such a circuit is also continuous and constant valued.

For an AC circuit, the current in a simple circuit is sinusoidal.  This means that light from a bulb in such a circuit "flickers" at twice the frequency of the current that is driving it.  For U.S. households, the flicker occurs at 120 Hz, which is a bit too fast to notice.  In Europe, their circuits run at 100 Hz, which is still a bit too fast to notice the flicker.

If the AC frequency is slowed down, or a sampled data system is used to observe an operating AC light bulb (e.g., a camera that is filming the bulb), the flicker becomes very noticeable.

Comment: I don't see how an incandescent bulb can flicker. It produces light by being heated, and it doesn't cool down enough between peaks to cool sufficiently to make any kind of difference in its light output.

Comment: @ThePhoton No, incandescent bulbs subject to 50Hz/220 or 60Hz/120 supplies reach a steady-state temperature and don't flicker.  At very low voltage, they might flicker a bit, and at lower frequencies they will flicker, but the light coming from them is due to thermal radiation, unlike fluorescent bulbs which do brighten and dim at 2X the AC line frequency.

Comment: How is this an ac analogy for light?

Comment: @BillDOe, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95llOO2HEOs

Comment: An analogy is just looking for any similarity, not necessarily based on the other. Like the expanding on the hose analogy for current, ac could have a pump and suction device that moves a flap in a hose loop one way then the other, for whatever reason.

Comment: But if we went by the analogy that could be from what is said here, an ac analogy for a hose would be turning it off and on, which makes it sound like an ac current would the same thing as turning a dc current off and on.

Comment: is that the analogy you are making?

Comment: @DavidWhite, since there's no mention of supply voltage, I don't think that YouTube video proves much of anything. As Bill N points out, at a low enough supply voltage an AC bulb may flicker, but even in the referenced YouTube video the bulb does not completely darken between peaks.

Comment: @user47014, in A/C current, the electrons wiggle back and forth around a fixed position.  It may be possible to do this with a water hose, but I can't think of any practical application for such a thing.

Comment: @BillDOe, I hope you don't want to get into a debate about the meaning of "flicker".

Comment: @DavidWhite, nope. "Flicker" can mean either shine unsteadily or flash intermittently. In this context the latter seems more fitting. But if you're in to longitudinally bisecting hair, an argument can be made either way.

Comment: @David White Yeah probably not practical, but then the question would be if you could do something similar with light (similar enough to call it an analogy).

Answer (score 1):

What BillDOe said. Light always travels as a wave, with a positive frequency. Visible light has a frequency of hundreds of trillions of hertz. You can have very low frequency electromagnetic waves, in the radio part of the spectrum, but the frequency must be greater than zero.

Comment: Electrons exist as waves also and yet ac and dc also exist

Comment: @user47014 Very true, but there' are some important differences between electrons and photons. An electron can have zero velocity, photons can't ever be locally at rest. Electrons are fermions, photons are bosons. AC and DC are actually descriptions of the electrical field associated with a collection of moving electrons, strictly speaking, it doesn't make sense to ask if a single electron is DC or AC.

Comment: However, we can talk about the wavefunction of a single electron, and that wavefunction can give us information about the position and momentum of that electron, within the limits imposed by the Heisenberg Uncertainty principle.

Comment: Yes electrons and photons are different, hence an analogy. Like a dog barking at a toy can be an analogy for a person yelling at their tv. The differences between the scenarios is beside the point.

Comment: I'm more saying that the question is about whether light can move around in a comparable way to currents, not about intrinsic properties of light and how they compare to currents. Similarities are the question, not differences. It would be like saying that dogs and humans can't be compared in the above scenario because most humans don't walk on all fours.

Comment: Or you could argue that movement of light and current are such different scenarios they can't be compared when it comes to ac and dc. Like finding an analogy for a dog barking at a toy for a human reading a book is too bizarre or something.

Comment: @user47014 Yes, I'm saying that (AFAIK) there is nothing in the behaviour of light that corresponds to electrical current in a circuit, and therefore the notion of AC vs DC isn't valid for light. But I'll ask one of our optics experts for his thoughts on this topic.

Comment: maybe the question is too subjective, since of course analogies can be made, it is more of a question of whether they are good or bad analogies

Answer (score 0):

Most lighting pre LED was AC lighting from household hydro supplies. If you power these same lightbulbs with DC you would get the exact same effect.  Dimmers for lights use a concept of pulsing the light 60 times per sec at varying pulse widths ( these are DC pulses ) where the pulses are made with various electronics components in the dimmer.  With LEDs the AC is converted to DC, LEDs need DC.

Comment: Is there a light analogy for ac that could come from this?